# Why is the asyncio library slower than threads for this I/O-bound operation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm writing a python program used to enumerate a site's domain name.For example,'a.google.com'.

First, I used the `threading` module to do this:

```
import string
import time
import socket
import threading
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

'''
enumerate a site's domain name like this:
1-9 a-z + .google.com
1.google.com
2.google.com
.
.
1a.google.com
.
.
zz.google.com

'''

start = time.time()
def create_host(char):
    '''
    if char is '1-9a-z'
    create char like'1,2,3,...,zz'
    '''
    for i in char:
        yield i
    for i in create_host(char):
        if len(i)>1:
            return False
        for c in char:
            yield c + i


char = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase
site = '.google.com'


def getaddr():
    while True:
        url = q.get()
        try:
            res = socket.getaddrinfo(url,80)
            print(url + ":" + res[0][4][0])
        except:
            pass
        q.task_done()

NUM=1000  #thread's num
q=Queue()

for i in range(NUM):
    t = Thread(target=getaddr)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

for host in create_host(char):
    q.put(host+site)
q.join()

end = time.time()

print(end-start)

'''
used time:
9.448670148849487
'''
```

Later, I read a book which said in some cases coroutines are faster than threads. So, I rewrote the code to use `asyncio`:

```
import asyncio
import string
import time


start = time.time()
def create_host(char):
    for i in char:
        yield i
    for i in create_host(char):
        if len(i)>1:
            return False
        for c in char:
            yield c + i


char = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase
site = '.google.com'

@asyncio.coroutine
def getaddr(loop, url):
    try:
        res = yield from loop.getaddrinfo(url,80)
        print(url + ':' + res[0][4][0])
    except:
        pass

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coroutines = asyncio.wait([getaddr(loop, i+site) for i in create_host(char)])
loop.run_until_complete(coroutines)

end = time.time()

print(end-start)


'''
time 
120.42313003540039
'''
```

Why is the `asyncio` version of  `getaddrinfo` is so slow? Am I misusing the coroutines somehow?

Comment: I'm not seeing nearly as much of a performance difference on my system. The threaded version was 20 seconds, the asyncio version was 24. Try removing the print statement from the `getaddr` method. Does that make a big different in performance? Printing releases the GIL, so many threads can do that concurrently, while `asyncio` can't. If printing is particularly slow on your system, it could account for the speed difference.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First, I can't reproduce a performance difference nearly as large as the one you're seeing on my Linux machine. I'm consistently seeing about 20-25 seconds for the threaded version, and between 24-34 seconds for the `asyncio` version.

Now, why is `asyncio` slower? There are a few things that contribute to this. First, the `asyncio` version has to print sequentially, but the threaded version doesn't. Printing is I/O, so the GIL can be released while it's happening. That means potentially two or more threads can print at the exact same time, though in practice it may not happen often, and probably doesn't make all that much difference in performance.

Second, and much more importantly, **the `asyncio` version of `getaddrinfo` is actually [just calling `socket.getaddrinfo` in a `ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6d91c4f40ba1/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#l461)**:

```
def getaddrinfo(self, host, port, *,
                family=0, type=0, proto=0, flags=0):
    if self._debug:
        return self.run_in_executor(None, self._getaddrinfo_debug,
                                    host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    else:
        return self.run_in_executor(None, socket.getaddrinfo,
                                    host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
```

It's using the default `ThreadPoolExecutor` for this, [which only has five threads](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6d91c4f40ba1/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#l40)*:

```
# Argument for default thread pool executor creation.
_MAX_WORKERS = 5
```

That's not nearly as much parallelism you want for this use-case. To make it behave more like the `threading` version, you'd need to use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with 1000 threads, by setting it as the default executor via `loop.set_default_executor`:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.set_default_executor(ThreadPoolExecutor(1000))
coroutines = asyncio.wait([getaddr(loop, i+site) for i in create_host(char)])
loop.run_until_complete(coroutines)
```

Now, this will make the behavior more equivalent to `threading`, but the reality here is **you're really not using asynchronous I/O - you're just using `threading` with a different API**. So the best you can do here is identical performance to the `threading` example.

Finally, you're not really running equivalent code in each example - the `threading` version is using a pool of workers, which are sharing a `queue.Queue`, while the `asyncio` version is spawning a coroutine for every single item in the url list. If I make the `asyncio` version to use a `asyncio.Queue` and pool of coroutines, in addition to the removing the print statements and making a larger default executor, I get essentially identical performance with both versions. Here's the new `asyncio` code:

```
import asyncio
import string
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

start = time.time()
def create_host(char):
    for i in char:
        yield i
    for i in create_host(char):
        if len(i)>1:
            return False
        for c in char:
            yield c + i


char = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase
site = '.google.com'

@asyncio.coroutine
def getaddr(loop, q):
    while True:
        url = yield from q.get()
        if not url:
            break
        try:
            res = yield from loop.getaddrinfo(url,80)
        except:
            pass

@asyncio.coroutine
def load_q(loop, q):
    for host in create_host(char):
        yield from q.put(host+site)
    for _ in range(NUM):
        yield from q.put(None)

NUM = 1000
q = asyncio.Queue()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.set_default_executor(ThreadPoolExecutor(NUM))
coros = [asyncio.async(getaddr(loop, q)) for i in range(NUM)]
loop.run_until_complete(load_q(loop, q))
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(coros))

end = time.time()

print(end-start)
```

And Output of each:

```
dan@dandesk:~$ python3 threaded_example.py
20.409344911575317
dan@dandesk:~$ python3 asyncio_example.py
20.39924192428589
```

Note that there is some variability due to the network, though. Both of them will sometimes be a few seconds slower than this.

** Note that in Python 3.8 and above, the default `ThreadPoolExecutor` creates `min(32, os.get_cpu_count() + 4)` threads. Depending on how many cores your machine has, this may result in enough threads being created for performance to of `asyncio` to more closely match the `threading` example. You'd have to test it and see.*

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me solve the problem.It makes me understand my asyncio version is not using asynchronous I/O.Then i searched an find the problem on tulip issues 160(https://code.google.com/p/tulip/issues/detail?id=160 )are also mentioned.I will use gevent in python2 or use aiodns in python3 to using asynchronous I/O.

Comment: Actually, asyncio is much slower due to the high impact of using coroutines. I have no numbers, so this is just a comment, instead of a post, but you can verify this with a simple http echo server written in both styles. Python + high performance async IO do not work together, sadly. Compared to Golang or Java, Python+asyncio (only IO bound), python is roughly 9x slower. ~32.000 Req/s vs 3.700 Req/s. Even the threaded solution is faster with python, as long as you do not use more than say 200 ~ 250 clients. Asyncio drops performance also at this number of clients.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe it is also a bug in the implementation. Sadly, there are no official benchmarks yet, so validating or proving my assumption is quite different right now...

Comment: Not sure 1000 threads gives you more parallelism than 5 threads. It should depend by the number of logical cores on the machine.

Comment: @MarcoSulla When you're dealing with I/O-bound threads, more threads does give you more parallelism. If you're dealing with CPU-bound threads, then I agree, you're capped by the number of cores on the machine. The OP's question is making DNS lookups, which is I/O-bound.

Comment: @MarcoSulla Though I guess it's really giving you more *concurrency*, not more parallelism.

Comment: Number of CPU cores is irrelevant when it comes to python threads (!= multiprocess) because of the GIL.

Comment: @Maresh As I said above, that's true if you're dealing with CPU-bound operations in the thread, but not if the threads are doing I/O.

Comment: This answer is not up to date anymore. The [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L835) now creates an Executor without parameters which in turn creates min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4) threads ([See docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)).

Comment: @Morty Thanks. I added a note to the answer mentioning that change.